# Как настроить swiper в react чтобы слайд всегда был по центру. А если они не помещаются, то первый слайд разрезается и добавляется с краю

Tags: reactjs, slider, swiper

Как сделать так, чтобы первый слад разрезался так, чтобы какой-то элемент был по центру, а вторая часть первого слайда добавилось с права?

[image: не верно]

так быть не должно слайд с права должен добавить невидимую часть с лева чтобы по центру расположился центральный слайд

[image: верно]

Должно быть как-то так